# Easiest way to create RSS feed from Rails 2.3.8 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

I have a legacy Rails 2.3.8 app I need to support and create an RSS feed for. This is ideally going to integrate with Google Merchant, using the following link: http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160589

I suppose my question is straight forward: what's the easiest way to create this RSS 2.0 feed with Rails 2.3.8? Is there a way to also create namespaces as Google requires in their feeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a project in the same version and this worked for me: http://railscasts.com/episodes/87-generating-rss-feeds